# Why browser does not show the image that is sent back by script?

Tags: image, path, hide

I have a script on the server that hides image path to users, whenever I type its URL on the URL bar some mysterious characters are shown, Can you guide me how to show this image on the browser, please?

http://search.icbar.org/Handler/Law.ashx?Method=mGetPic&ID=66472460DF61493291202DA80A51FE7B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are looking at is indeed a JPEG image - I've verified that.

Try sticking this in a local page:

```
<img src="http://search.icbar.org/Handler/Law.ashx?Method=mGetPic&ID=66472460DF61493291202DA80A51FE7B" />
```

Your browser is attempting to show the file as a text file, which it isn't. If you "Save Link As" on the link, you will download the file. Give it a .jpg file extension and you're golden...

Answer (score 0):

Your server sends the wrong text/html mime type, you need to change it to image/jpeg.

Comment: The script on the server is not mine and I cannot access it.